# How to run a custom js function in playwright

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, webautomation, playwright, chrome-devtools-protocol

How can I run a custom js function in playwright? For example show an alert. I have already tried this way but it did not work.

```
var url = await page.evaluate(async() => {
  await function alert() {
    alert("alert");
  }

  await alert();
});
```

Comment: Looks like a stack overflow... won't the `alert` fn keep calling itself?

Comment: @weltschmerz Not sure, I guess if you say so. This is just for example. New to this. Maybe that is why it is not working. Can you share a fix?

Comment: Well, first, I don't think you need any of the `await` and `async` keywords except for maybe the very first `await` (and you're using them wrong anyway, since you're using `await` on a function declaration). So basically try getting rid of all the `async` and `await` statements inside the call to `page.evaluate`, run it again, and let me know what you see.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would just do:

```
await page.evaluate(() => alert("alert"))
```

But keep in mind, that alert's are blocking in the JavaScript browser world and dismissed automatically by Playwright. See [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-dialog/) how to interact with them (dismiss e.g.)